# Error trying to deploy to heroku (following ror tutorial) PG::Error: ERROR: column "password_digest" of relation "users" already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku

So I'm following the http://www.railstutorial.org/book, and evrything works fine locally (running sqlight3).

I get the following error when I try

> heroku run rake db:migrate

This is what the error message looks like

> Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4049
>   Migrating to AddPasswordDigestToUsers (20140817014655)
>   == 20140817014655 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =========================
>   -- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string) PG::Error: ERROR:  column "password_digest" of relation "users" already exists : ALTER
>   TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "password_digest" character varying(255) rake
>   aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later
>   migrations canceled:
>
> PG::Error: ERROR:  column "password_digest" of relation "users"
>   already exists : ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "password_digest"
>   character
>   varying(255)/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in
>   `exec'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:442:in `block in log'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:437:in `log'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in`
>   execute'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:360:in
>   `add_column'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:395:in`
>   add_column'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:629:in
>   `block in method_missing'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in`
>   block in say_with_time'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in
>   `say_with_time'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in`
>   method_missing'
>   /app/db/migrate/20140817014655_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:3:in
>   `change'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:575:in`
>   exec_migration'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in
>   `block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in
>   `with_connection'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:557:in`
>   migrate'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:713:in
>   `migrate'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:963:in`
>   block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in
>   `block in ddl_transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:203:in`
>   block in transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in
>   `within_new_transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:203:in`
>   transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in`
>   ddl_transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:962:in
>   `execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:924:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in
>   `each'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in`
>   migrate'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in
>   `up'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:746:in`
>   migrate'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in
>   `block (2 levels) in ' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See
>   full trace by running task with --trace)

I already tried heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL and then retrying.
Also tried adding /spec, /lib, /script, /features, /cucumber.yml to .slugignore

This is what my schema looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140818041701) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.boolean  "admin",           default: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"

end
```

And this is what my password digest migration looks like

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `password_digest` column in your table and with migration `AddPasswordDigestToUsers` you are trying to create another one that's why it creating issue. Remove migration `AddPasswordDigestToUsers` and try run `rake db:migrate` again. Sqlite3 not producing any error in such cases. if you write `intege` instead of `integer` in migration it will not produce any error if you use sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply delete the password digest migration file, it will solve the short term problem of deploying to heroku but then it won't be available for collaborators to pull down and set up their database locally. They will run into issues and may create another migration file which creates the same problem.

I'm not sure the best solution, but this seems to be working out for me so far:

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    if Rails.env == "production"
    else
      add_column :users, :password_digest, :string   
    end
  end
end
```